# JavaScript THREE.js webgl spotlight rendering

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I'm playing with webgl/JavaScript/THREE and a spotlight. And I see unexpected results. And I don't understand what's going on, and I'm hoping you can point me in the right direction. In my particular case, the bizarre behavior is when the spotlight is behind the character, but the light is rendered as it's coming from the front. I apologize, I think it's best if you take a look here to see what I mean

http://dhkgames.com/games/redshifted

. Please note that in my tests This website worked in chrome and Internet Explorer, but for some reason not in Firefox. Also, please be patient, the test website is hosted in Singapore, so it may take up to one minute onto the character is downloaded and rendered in the middle of the screen

. What I'm interested in is to understand if the spotlight works as designed, or maybe I can update vertex/fragment programs.
 As a secondary goal, in the spotlight The pants and the jacket material renders somehow differently, and once again I'm not sure why, so if you have some pointers for this as well It would be much appreciated!

. Lastly, I apologize for misspellings, my arms and eyes don't work very well, and I use voice recognition software to interact with my computer…

. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that I was missing the following line in my code

```
player.scale.set(1,1,-1);
```